# Getting subarray from one array

Tags: c, arrays

There is an exercise that asks for the biggest sub-array inside one specific array, and the sub-array should not have repeated elements.

> I do not have to worry about complexity and efficiency right now

The array is [8,2,2,3,4,1,6,5,1,7]

As far as i understand, the biggest subarray without repeated elements is:
[2,3,4,1,6,5,7]

But they say that my function should output the [2,3,4,1,6,5]

Why?

This is my code:

```
int existe(int chk, int v[], int tam){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        if(v[i]==chk){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int removeb(int v[], int n){
    int i, max, j;
    max = 0; 

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(v[i]>max){
            max = v[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(v[i]==max){
            j=i;
            while(j<n){
                v[j]=v[j+1];
                j++;
            }
            return j-1;
        }
    }
    return n;
}


int maxuniqueseq(int v[], int N){
    int i, j, newsize;
    int tmp[N];

    //newsize = removeb(v, N);
    printf("%d\n", N);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        tmp[i] = v[i];
    }
    for(i=0, j=0; i<N; i++){
        if(existe(tmp[i],v, i)){
            ;
        }else{
            v[j]=tmp[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    newsize = removeb(v, j);


    return newsize;
}
```

> Output with the above array:
>
> [2,3,4,1,6,5,7]
>
> With another example:
>
> [8,2,2,3,4,12,6,5,1,7]
>
> outputs: [8,2,3,4,6,5,1,7]

Comment: If you think `[2,3,4,1,6,5,7]` is the biggest subarray then what happened to the `1` between `5` and `7` which is there in the original array ?

Comment: You would be needing biggest contiguous subarray. Else for biggest subarray it would be [8,2,3,4,1,6,5,7]. In either case your answer is wrong.

Comment: as i understand it, if i have [1,2,3,4,5], the biggest subarray is [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @skills why would it be so? why poor 5 is not good enough?

Comment: what about 5, it should be [1,2,3,4,5]. You need biggest contiguous subarray, it can be array itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your interpretation of sub-array.

This is what a sub-array is

> A subarray is commonly defined as a part or section of an array.

Hence the elements you are selecting need to be **contiguous**.

With an example,

> suppose **[10, 20, 50, 15, 10, 25, 45]** is the array,
>
> a **sub-array** for this would be **[10, 20, 50]**
>
> where as [10, 50, 25] can not be called as a sub-array.
>
> And the **biggest sub-array** without repeated elements would be **[ 20, 50, 15, 10, 25, 45]**

So change your code and give another try!

Comment: What does contiguous mean? English is not my language.

Can you give me an example of an array and a subarray and explain why is that a sub-array? Thank you so much .

Comment: @skills contiguous, means all adjacent and continuous elements.

Comment: @skills It would be useful if you write in ypur profile where you are  from.:)

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish but they do not speak about contiguous in the exercise, the answer [2,3,4,1,6,5] has elements that are not adjacent and continuous, after 1, why 6?

Comment: @skills in the original array, 6 is right next to 1

Comment: @skills considering the array `[8,2,2,3,4,1,6,5,1,7]`, `[2,3,4,1,6,5]` has elements that are adjacent and continuous.